# Spring Security OAuth 2.0 requiring authentication token for anonymous resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to create a site. The pages that are available to anyone are the landing page, the login page, the register page, the about us page, and the contact page as seen below.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .authorizeRequests()                                
          .antMatchers("/", "/join", "/login", "/about", "/contact").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()                            
        .and().exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
          .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

Here is my OAuth2 config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer 
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "authorization_code")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds("business-resource")
                .secret("secret");
    }

}
```

And my controller:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class BusinessAccountController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BusinessAccountController.class);

    @Autowired
    BusinessUserService businessUserService;

    /*URL mapping constants for each particular controller method*/
    private static final String LOGIN_URL_MAPPING =             "/login";
    private static final String USER_ENDPOINT_URL_MAPPING =     "/user";
    private static final String ACCOUNT_CREATION_URL_MAPPING =  "/join";

    /**
     * @param principal
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(USER_ENDPOINT_URL_MAPPING)
     public Principal user(Principal principal) {
       return principal;
     }

    @RequestMapping(value = LOGIN_URL_MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessUser> login(@RequestBody BusinessUser inputUser) {
        BusinessUser requestedUser = businessUserService.findByUsername(inputUser.getUsername());

        if(requestedUser != null)
            if(BCrypt.checkpw(inputUser.getPassword(), requestedUser.getPassword()))
                return new ResponseEntity<>(requestedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
...
```

For some reason, every single page requires an authentication token(gives a 401 unauthorized response), even the ones I specified `permitAll()` on (login, contact, about us, etc...). **Why is Spring asking for an authentication token for the pages I specified to be accessed without authentication?**

Side note: If I generate an access token, I'm able to register, log in, and access unauthorized pages. I want to be able to access the specified pages in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` without an authentication token.

Comment: i've experienced a similar problem, i fixed it configuring in my OAuth2 config not in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Did you figure out which component was causing the issue? I've tried reordering my method calls (as suggested by other questions) but nothing has worked.

Comment: i've noticed on the order of ejecution, you can set the priority with `@Order`